# How can I write the JavaScript once correctly & call it multiple place

Tags: javascript

I am getting the desired output but at the same time my JavaScript is also getting generated multiple times on the page. Please advice as how to improvise this code;

I am using a view while using codeigniter 3. View code is here under;

1) This is the View mainPage.php

```html
<?php ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Sampledata</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/css/newcro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/css/newcro2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="overflow-x: hidden;">
<!-- <body> -->

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row fresh featuredproduct">

<?php foreach ($fProducts as $fProduct){ ?>
        
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2 "> 
                
                <div class="card am productcard">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url().'data/img/product/'.$fProduct->pro_image; ?>" />
                        <div class="container ma">
                                <p2><?php echo $fProduct->product_name;?></p2>
                                <form action="/action_page.php">
                                <select id="<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id.'master' ?>" name="cars" class="f5" onchange="return <?php echo $fProduct->pro_id.'changeStyle()'?>">
                                
                                        
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { if ($item->product_name == $fProduct->product_name) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $item->htmlId;?>" >
                                                <?php echo $item->list_val;?>
                                        </option>
<?php }
}?>
                                </select>
                                </form>
                        <div class=" f3" >
                        <!--"f3" user defined-->
                        <?php foreach ($items as $item) { if ($item->pro_id == $fProduct->pro_id) { ?>
                                <div id="<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id. $item->htmlId;?>" style="display: none;" ><p4> MRP:<strike>₹ <?php echo $item->strike_rate;?></strike></p4>
                                <p5>₹ <?php echo $item->pro_rate;?></p5></div>



<?php } 
}?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function <?php echo $fProduct->pro_id.'changeStyle()'?>{
    var selected =document.getElementById("<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id.'master' ?>"); 
    var myselection = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].value; 
    if (myselection =='one')
        {
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."one" ?>').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."two" ?>').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."three" ?>').style.display='none';

        }
        else if (myselection =='two')
        {
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."two" ?>').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."one" ?>').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."three" ?>').style.display='none';

        }
        else if(myselection =='three')
        {
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."three"?>').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."one" ?>').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $fProduct->pro_id."two" ?>').style.display='none';

        }
        return false;


    }
    
        <?php echo $fProduct->pro_id.'changeStyle()'.';'?>

            
    

</script>




                        </div>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <div class="row input-group-prepend f6">
                                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-sm-3 "><span class="input-group-text f7" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Qty</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-sm-3"><input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control cr" aria-label="Sizing example input" min="1" max="5">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-sm-3 "><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm r" type="button">ADD<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart "></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>   <hr>  
                
        </div><!-- col End Here -->   <?php } ?>
        <div><hr></div>


</div>
</div>
<p><a href="<?php base_url(); ?>test" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Next Page</a></p> <br>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is newcro.css file

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.fresh a img{width:20px; margin-left: 15px;border:none;}

.fresh p1{padding-left: 15px; font-size:10px;}

.ma { font-size:15px; text-align:center;font-weight: bold; }

.fresh{margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 5px;}
.cla{height:10px;}

.cla p{text-align: right;}





.fresh:hover{
 background-color: white;
 color:darkgreen;
}

.card:hover{-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 9px 40px -12px; rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow:-1px 9px 40px -12px ; rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: -1px 9px 40px -12px; rgba(0,0,0,0.75)}

.imae:hover{-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 9px 40px -12px; rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow:-1px 9px 40px -12px ; rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: -1px 9px 40px -12px; rgba(0,0,0,0.75)}


.coloo{height:px; padding-left: 50px;}

.colooo{height:325px;}

.cls{background-color: #DCDCDC; width:200px;margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;}

 
.fresh p3{font-size: 10px; color:grey;padding-left: 15px;}

.fresh ul li{font-size: 10px; color:grey; list-style: none;}

.fresh ul li a i{font-size: 20px; color:grey;}
.int{height: 20px;}

.freshx{padding-top: 40px;}

.cro{padding-top: 0px;}

.crob{width:75%;}

.cr{height: 30px; width:55px; }

.r{height:25px; width:80px; margin-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 25px;}

.red i{color:red; font-size: 18px;}

.red{color: grey;font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}

.g i{color:grey; font-size: 18px; }

.g{color: grey;font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; border-right: 1px solid green;padding-right: 5px;}

.smal{font-size: 10px;padding-top: 5px;}

.smal p5{font-size: 20px;}

.rt{width:25px;}

.buton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 650px;
  margin-top: 10px;  

}

.n {justify-content: center;font-size: 35px; padding-top: 60px;}

.j i{margin-left: -200px;margin-top: 18px; }

.j{font-size:15px;margin-right: 100px; }

.buton1{background-color: #ff5c03 ; height:25px; width:180px; padding-bottom:20px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;}

.z
{
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  font-size: 25px;
  color:#778899;
}
.buton2 
{
  width:100px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  height:60px;
}
.y
{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.buton2 br
{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.divide
{
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}
.reorder
{
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  border: 2px solid  grey; 
  
  margin-left: -210px;

  
}

.productreorder
{
   background-color: #DCDCDC;
  border: 2px solid  grey; 
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: -210px;
}
.mdl-sty h1
{
  text-align:  center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.mdl-bdy 
{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.qualty p
{
  text-align: center;
}
.qualty textarea
{
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.boxe {
  border: 2px solid black ;
  width:350px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.boxe i
{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
}
.top
{
  padding-top: 10px;
  
}

.top a
{
  color: black;
}
.ter
{
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom ul li
 {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mop 
{
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.heght
{
  height: 20px;
}

.dropl
{
  width: 200px;
}
.dropl option p
{
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.classic1
{
  height:100px;
}

                       /*index-3 css*/

.fresh1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  margin-left: -5px; 
margin-bottom: 20px;}



.fresh1 a
{ 
  font-size:10px ;
  text-align: center;
}                       

.f1
{
  width: 120px;
  height:120px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.f2
{
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.productcard
{
  width: 200PX;
}

.productcard p2
{
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.f3 p4 strike
{
   font-size: 10px;
   color:red; 
}

.f3 p4 
{
   font-size: 10px;
   font-weight: bold; 
}

.f3 p5
{
   font-size: 15px;
   color:green; 
}

.f3
{
  text-align: center;

}

.f4
{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  width: 190px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.f4 li
{
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.f5
{

  width:165px;
}

.f6
{
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

.f7
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.f8 i
{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.f9
{
  color: yellow;
}

.f10
{
  color: red;
}




div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;

}

div.sticky h6
{
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.sticky a
{
  color: black;
}
.f12 
{
  text-align: center;
}

.f13
{
  margin-right: -190px;
}

.prod h4
{
  padding-top: 20px;

}

.carouselmargin
{
  margin-right: -20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.categoryheadings
{
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.singleproduct img
{
  width:400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
 
  padding: 30px;
  
}

.singleproduct button
{
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.singleproductwishlist button
{
  margin-top: 10px;
   width: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.sproductrow
{
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.sproductmrp p4 strike
{
   font-size: 10px;
   color:red; 
}

.sproductmrp p4 
{
   font-size: 10px;
   font-weight: bold; 
}

.sproductmrp p5
{
   font-size: 15px;
   color:green; 
}

.sproductmrp p
{
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.customerreviews
{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

This is newcro2.css

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.header{
 background-color: #FF704D;
 justify-content: center;
 height:25px;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
  
}

.veg a img{
 width:15px;
    height:18px;
    margin-left: -15px;}

.veg a{
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-left:0px;
 margin-right: 190px;
}

.pincodemargin{margin-top: -50px; width:40px;margin-left: 50px;}

.place{width:650px; height:40; }

.place input{ background-color: #D9D9D9;  }

.place button{ background-color: #D9D9D9; margin-left: -5px; height:40px;margin-top:-1px; }

.u{padding-top: 30px;}
.u a{color:black; font-weight:bold;}

.u img{width:50px;height:50px; margin-left: 40px;}

.u button img{width:50px;height:50px; margin-left: 0px; }

.pink{background-color: #FF704D; width:140px;height:40px;padding-top: 8px; margin-left:-10px;padding-left: 20px; color:black;}

.gree{background-color: #7ed957; padding-right: 150px; }

.gr b{color:black;}

.green{background-color: #7ed957; padding-left: 580px; margin-right:-14px;}

.under{height:40px; margin-left: -10px; }

.menu7{justify-content: center; font-size:30px; background-color: #f4bc33; height:40px; margin-top: 10px;}

.menu7 p{font-family: courier new,courier,monospace;color:#ea2b2b;}

.menu8 {justify-content: center;font-size: 35px; padding-top: 30px; margin-right: }

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.cente {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.centered{width:40px;}

.centered1{padding-left:125px;}

.centered2 img{width:100px;}

.centered2{padding-left:110px;}

.centered3{text-align: center;margin-bottom: 4px;font-weight:bold;}

.centered4{padding-left:130px;}

.centered5{margin-left:-40px;font-weight:bold;padding-top: 30px;}

.centered6{padding-left: 40px;}

.centered12 p{font-size:25px;font-weight: bold;color:black; text-align: center;}

.centered13{padding-left: 130px;}

.centered14{padding-left: 170px;}

.centered15{margin-left: 135px;}

.centered17{text-align:center;font-weight: bold;background-color: #d9d9d9;margin-top: 10px;height:40px;padding-top: 10px;}

.centered18 {text-align: center;font-size: 45px;font-family: courier new,courier,monospace;color:#ea2b2b;}

.centered18 p7{text-align: center;font-size: 30px;font-family: courier new,courier,monospace;color:black;}

.centered32{margin-right: -15px;}

.classic img{margin-top:30px; width:1300px; margin-left: 45px;}

.centered4 p{font-size:25px; color:black;}

.clssy{margin-left:35px;}

.clss{margin-top: 20px;}

.fresh img{width:180px; height:180px;border:2px solid #AAF09A;margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;border-radius: 10px;background-color: #C2FBB5;}

.featuredproduct
{
  margin-right:-220px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.am{background-color:#cdece9;}



.imae img{width:200px;height:200px;border:2px solid pink;border-radius:15px;background-color: #f6d2d6;}

.ma{background-color: white;}

.sma{width:160px;}

.but{width:100px;margin-left: 165px;}

.yes{text-align: center;font-weight:bold;}

.slied{height:300px; margin-top: 40px;}

.pade{ margin-top: 30px;height:130px; width:1300px;margin-left:45px;border:4px solid grey;  text-align: center;border-top: 1px solid grey;}

.cent {display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  
  }

.sty li{list-style: none;}

.ma p4{font-size: 10px;}

.ma p5{color:green;}

.imae p4{font-size: 10px;}

.imae p5{color:green;}

.clay{margin-left: 10px;}

.r i{font-size:20px; padding-left: 10px;}




.trans{
 position:left;
 color:black;
    width:20px;
}


.nav{
 text-align: right;
}
 
.sty{
 color:#3b5999;

}




.button {
  background-color: none;
  border: none;
  color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  }
  


.veg li{list-style: none;}

.menu{ text-align: right; font-size: 20px;}

.product{
 justify-content: center;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.topnav{
 background-color: white;
 height:25px;
}
.menux{
 background-color: white; margin-left: 15px;}
.menu1 img{height:125px; width:125px; margin-left: 20px; }
.menux input{width:750px;}
.menux form{padding-top: 15px;}



.new{padding-left: 50px;}

.fresh a img{width:20px;}

.fresh p1{padding-left: 10px; font-size:10px;}


.menu24{font-size: 20px; border:5px solid grey ;border-radius: 8px; text-align: center;

}



@media only screen and (max-width: 620px)


  
.topnav{
 width:100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
}

.navigation{
 padding-right: 400px;

}
.responsivrimage{
 height:50%;
 width:150%;
}
```

Comment: Nobody is going to read all of that, please provide the smallest part of the code that can help us help you

Comment: The JavaScript is written inside the foreach loop and hence getting replicated as well on the page.

Comment: You'd better take a look at [Ask a Better question in StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)